# users device fails data property encoding, but works on another device

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

Had a very unusual bug with a handful of our users (less than 10 known out of thousands). Some of the objects that we store in coreData use date types. For some reason, on a specific person's device, some objects would fail during initialization whenever the JSON tried to map the dateString to our formatter.

```
static let iso8601DateTime: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)[enter image description here][1]
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    return formatter
}()
```

When I made a breakpoint, all JSON time strings came in this format:

I was puzzled why some objects were successfully mapping at that point and others failed despite all of them returning in that format. By change, I read an issue on Apple's support website about language & region with ISO8601. I changed his region from US -> UK -> (back to) US, and found that all of the issues were resolved and He was able to use the application as normal.

Some advice I received said to specify a locale for the dateformatter, but I haven't been able to test yet.

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

Any idea why basically soft-refreshing this setting resolved it (setting to another and then back again)?

Comment: 12/24 hour setting. The advice to use `en_US_POSIX` solves this.

Comment: would this create an issue with devices outside the US?

Comment: @leahyjwilliam no this is required when parsing fixed date formats